# Ramanujan identity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

$$\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{1^j}{\sqrt{j} \left(\sqrt{j-1}+\sqrt{j}\right)^2}=\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right) \sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{\sqrt{j}}$$
although numerically they do not coincide using Mathematica (it must be a matter of adjusting the calculation digits) the case that using other positive values curious results are obtained, but I have not been able to check if the results of the table calculated using polynomial approximation are correct  could you checky the results
$$\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{z^j}{\sqrt{j} \left(\sqrt{j-1}+\sqrt{j}\right)^2}$$ gives
[image]

$$N\left[\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{1^j}{\sqrt{j} \left(\sqrt{j-1}+\sqrt{j}\right)^2}=\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right) \sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{\sqrt{j}},\{\infty ,20\}\right]$$
Now Mathematica say it is true .
This identity appears in The Lost Notebook entry 9 and 13
Also $$\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{z^j}{j^s}=\text{Li}_s(z)$$
Answering comments about their possible divergence, the polylog function for values z=2 is$$N\left[\text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}(2)=-1.61006-2.12893 i\right]$$
With which it is possible that the values thus calculated make sense, it can be seen as an analytical extension of the Zeta function
but I would like if someone can corroborate the numerical calculations,

Comment: Please show the *Mathematica* code that you used that convinced you that the first two equations do not coincide.

Comment: Also, please give a reference where this appears in Ramanujan's writings.

Comment: The sum does not converge for `z>1` so your results for `z=2,3,4,5` are incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only closed form for series:

$$\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{z^j}{\sqrt{j} \left(\sqrt{j-1}+\sqrt{j}\right)^2}=2 \text{Li}_{-\frac{1}{2}}(z)-2 z \text{Li}_{-\frac{1}{2}}(z)-\text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}(z)$$

for: $-1\leq z< 1$

```
Grid[Table[{z, NSum[z^j/(Sqrt[j] (Sqrt[j - 1] + Sqrt[j])^2), {j, 1, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 20], 
N[2 PolyLog[-(1/2), z] - 2 z PolyLog[-(1/2), z] - PolyLog[1/2, z],
20]}, {z, -1, 1, 1/5}], Frame -> All] // Quiet
```

And

```
 Limit[2 PolyLog[-(1/2), z] - 2 z PolyLog[-(1/2), z] - PolyLog[1/2, z], z -> 1]

 (*-Zeta[1/2]*)
```

Comment: @ Mariusz good job it correct for the above result divide by 1/z (I forget include in the formula above $$ N[1/z (2 PolyLog[-(1/2), z] - 2 z PolyLog[-(1/2), z] - 
    PolyLog[1/2, z]), 20]$$

Comment: I see it easy to get using $$\text{Apart}\left[\frac{z^j}{\sqrt{j+1} \left(\sqrt{j}+\sqrt{j+1}\right)^2}\right]$$ and get  $$-2 \sqrt{j} z^j+\frac{2 j z^j}{\sqrt{j+1}}+\frac{z^j}{\sqrt{j+1}}$$ the rest it is obvius

Answer (score 3):

The two sums differ mostly by convex monotone against oscillating aorund the limit.

So lets look at the even lenghts only

```
   f[n_] := Sum[1/(Sqrt[j] (Sqrt[j] + Sqrt[j + 1])^2), {j, 1, 2 n}]
   g[n_] := Sum[(-1)^(j + 1)/Sqrt[j] , {j, 1, 2 n}]
   Limit[f[n], n -> \[Infinity]]
   Limit[g[n], n -> \[Infinity]]


 2+Zeta[1/2]

 Limit[(-((-1+Sqrt[2]) Zeta[1/2])-
     ((-1)^(2 n) Zeta[1/2,12+n,IncludeSingularTerm->False])/Sqrt[2]+
     ((-1)^(2 n) Zeta[1/2,1+n,IncludeSingularTerm->False])/Sqrt[2],
      n->\[Infinity]]
```

The n-independent constant without $(-1)^n$-factors is the candiate for the limit

Define function tables with high precision, take the mean of neighbors for G

```
F[n_]:=FoldList[(N[#+1/(Sqrt[#2] (Sqrt[#2]+Sqrt[#2+1])^2 ),128]&),0,Range[1,2n]]
G[n_]:=((#+RotateLeft[#])/2&)
         [FoldList[(N[#+(-1)^(#2+1)Sqrt[#2],128]&),0,Range[1,2n]]]

ListPlot[ {1/(2 + Zeta[1/2]) F[100], -1/( (Sqrt[2] - 1) Zeta[1/2]) G[100]} ,
  PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}]
```

[image: ListPlot of sums]

The convergence is slow but seems to work.